# Multiple resources in one view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I want to display a list of images and their respective comments. Like:

```
Image url                    | Format        | Comments
http://example.com/img.jpg   | 1280x420      | [Comment 1], [Comment 2] ...show all  ...show all  
http://example.com/img2.jpg  | 630x590       | [Comment 1], [Comment 2] ...show all
```

I have two resouces: /images and /comments/{image_id}

What is the recommended way to fetch the comments for each image to be able to display them on the same row? Does Marionette have a helper for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, these look like a good place to use relational models. Backbone doesn't support these out of the box, so you'll need a plugin. Have a look at [Backbone-Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or [supermodel.js](http://pathable.github.com/supermodel/). These projects provide better forms of model nesting than the default implementation. From there, use nested composite views to render the collections.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know Marionette does not have such helper. I think you can use something simple like:

```
var ImageComments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    options || (options = {});
    this.imageId = options.imageId;
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  urlRoot: function() {
    return 'comments/' + this.imageId;
  }
});

var id = 1,
    image = new Image({ id: id }),
    comments = new ImageComments(null, { imageId: id });

$.when(image.fetch(), comments.fetch()).done(function() {
  // .. do your things with image & comments 
});
```

This describes simple case, if that's commonly used in your application you might want to implement your own fetch method (e.g. for image, that will also fetch comments) or use plugins like [Backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or [Backbone-associations](https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested composite views.

http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

You can also do old fashioned in template loops for the comments

http://www.headspring.com/an-underscore-templates-primer/